# Only Two out of the 5 speakers on my HP Envy 15 x360 work when in linux. Bang and Olufsen

Tags: sound, hp

I asked a question before, but after learning more about my issue the older question was far to vague so I am gonna try to include as much info as possible here.

I have an HP Envy 15 x360 convertible, which as far as I know has 5 speakers, two on the side of the keyboard, two on the bottom cover and one subwoofer.

When I am in linux only the two under the laptop seem to work, meaning no bass frequencies are produced.

I have tried fixing this with alsa-tools-gui and hdajackretask but have not made and progress.

My laptop is the Ryzen version, I am not sure if this matters but all the fixes I have found seem to be related to intel and that may be a factor in why they don't work for me.

I am running a dual boot with windows 11, safe boot and fast boot are disabled.

The final bit of info that may be relevant is that the speakers are bang and olufsen.

Edit: I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You must specify your Ubuntu version for this forum. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722205/hp-envy-x360-2022-ryzen-edition-speakers-not-working?rq=1

Comment: You have omitted your Ubuntu release,  `sudo lshw -class audio`.Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].